# How do I prevent buffer overflow converting a double to char?

Tags: c, arrays, string

I'm converting a double to a char string:

```
char txt[10];
double num;

num = 45.344322345

sprintf(txt, "%.1f", num);
```

and using ".1f" to truncate the decimal places, to the tenths digit.
i.e. - txt contains 45.3

I usually use precision in sprintf to ensure the char buffer is not overflowed.
How can I do that here also truncating the decimal, without using snprintf?

(i.e. if num = 345694876345.3 for some reason)

Thanks

**EDIT** If num is > buffer the result no longer matters, just do not want to crash. Not sure what would make the most sense in that case.

**EDIT2** I should have made it more clear than in just the tag, that this is a C program.
I am having issues using snprintf in a C program. [I don't want to add any 3rd party libraries.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2815393/can-i-use-cstdio-in-a-c-program)

Comment: What would you want the result to be, if it couldn't print the result properly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `snprintf()` , which will tell you how many bytes were *not* printed. In general, you should size your array to be large enough to handle the longest string representation of the target integer type. If not known in advance, use `malloc()` (or `asprintf()`, which is non-standard, but present on many platforms).

**Edit**

`snprintf()` will fail gracefully if the format exceeds the given buffer, it won't overflow. If you don't need to *handle* that, then simply using it will solve your problem. I can't think of an instance where you would not *want* to handle that, but then again, I'm not working on whatever you are working on :)

Answer (score 3):

Why not just make your buffer big enough to hold the largest possible string representation of a double?

Assuming a 64-bit double using the IEEE standard for floating point arithmetic, which uses 52 bits for a mantissa: 2^52 = 4,503,599,627,370,500. So we need 16 characters to hold all the digits before and after the decimal point. 19 considering the decimal point, sign character and null terminator.

I would just use a buffer size of at least 20 characters and move on.

If you need to print a double using scientific notation, you will need to add enough space for the exponent. Assuming a 11 bit signed exponent, that's another 4 characters for the exponent plus a sign for the exponent and the letter 'E'. I would just go with 30 characters in that case.

Comment: I'd just make it 40 and move on.  Unless it's an array, that 40 bytes is a lot cheaper than your time.  But I like snprintf too.

Answer (score 2):

If you absolutely must do it on your own, count the digits in the number before trying to convert:

```
int whole = num;
int wholeDigits = 0;
do {
    ++wholeDigits;
}
while (whole /= 10);

double fraction = num - (int) num;
int decimallDigits = 0;
while (fraction > 0) {
    ++decimalDigits;
    fraction *= 10;
    fraction = fraction - (int) fraction;
}

int totalLength = decimalDigits ? wholeDigits + decimalDigits + 1 : wholeDigits;
```

You should probably verify that this ad-hoc code works as advertised before relying on it to guard against crashes. I recommend that you use `snprintf` or something similar instead of my code, as others have said.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you want to do it without `snprintf`? You should be using `snprintf` regardless of whether your format string contains a double, another string or anything else, really. As far as I can see, there's no reason *not* to.