# Can I use cstdio in a C program?

Tags: c, include

I get a ton of errors in cstdio when I add `#include <cstdio>`
to the C program.

```
c:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio .NET 2003\Vc7\include\cstdio(17) : error C2143: syntax error : missing '{' before ':'
c:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio .NET 2003\Vc7\include\cstdio(17) : error C2059: syntax error : ':'
```

Thanks

**EDIT** - I would like to use **snprintf**, which is why I am trying to include this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You want `#include <stdio.h>`. `cstdio` is the C++ wrapper for the C header.

**Edit:** MSVC only supports the elements in C99 that form a subset of C++.

[This site](http://www.ijs.si/software/snprintf/) has a C implementation of `snprintf()` licensed under the GPL.

Comment: would like to use snprintf, can that be used in C?

Comment: If he wants to ever ship his code, he now has to open it due to GPL linkage.  MSVC provides similar functionality, so I think it would be better for him to create a wrapper around both snprintf / sprintf_s and call his wrapper code.

Comment: @SB: Good point. It was just an example to get things rolling.

Answer (score 1):

With Visual Studio, I believe you have to use sprintf_s or something similar.  See [this.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ce3zzk1k.aspx)  There's also [vsnprintf](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1kt27hek%28VS.80%29.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

MSVC offers the [`_snprintf`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2ts7cx93(VS.71).aspx) function in `stdio.h`.

If you prefer not to use the leading underscore, you can:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define snprintf _snprintf
```

This is a C library function, not specifically related to C++ (although you can use it there too).

Comment: I would strongly recommend *not* aliasing one to the other like that. `_snprintf` does not have standard C `snprintf` semantics (specifically, it does *not* guarantee NUL termination, and it will return -1 instead of the necessary buffer size if given an insufficiently large buffer).